# grails 2.0 - installing resources plugin gives version 1.1.3, not version 1.1.6 [ ** Don't use install-plugin **]

Tags: grails

Grails 2.0 projects currently come with resources plugin 1.1.5, which appears to have several dependency problems (e.g. see answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105084/grails-simple-app-to-test-spring-security-core-secure-channel-on-heroku)).  I'm using IntelliJ, and while I updated BuildConfig.groovy to

```
  runtime ":resources 1.1.6"
```

which appears to cause IntelliJ to bring in new files, it doesn't update the plugins section  (it still shows the old 1.1.5).

So then I did an uninstall-plugin-in resources, which got rid of the plugin in the Grails view.  I then did install-plugin resources, and even though the [resources plugin website shows](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) it is at 1.1.6, I got a resources-1.1.3 plugin.

How is this possible?  That's several versions back now. Additionally the website says it was updated 3 weeks ago to version 1.1.6.

Should one ever even use install-plugin?   Can someone please tell me the preferred way to bring plugins into projects?

Thanks.

P.S.  Not clear how to download this plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for the [dependency resolution DSL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#ivy) is `group:name:version`.

For the resources plugin it should be `runtime ":resources:1.1.6"`

The `install-plugin` command has been unofficially deprecated in favor of the dependency resolution DSL.

Comment: Thanks James.  For plugins like spring-security-core that are compile type plugins and require additional commands to be run, e.g. s2-quickstart, after adding compile spring-security-core to the plugins section in BuildConfig.groovy, what does one do next to get the plugin into the environment, so that a command like s2-quickstart can be run?

Comment: @Ray use [`grails refresh-dependencies`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/refresh-dependencies.html) to process the changes and then `grails s2-quickstart ...` as usual.

Comment: I'll have to file a JIRA on lack of documentation on this, as this command isn't referenced in Chapter 3 of the Grails 2.0 documentation, and when one searches the entire document (http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html) for refresh-dependencies nothing comes up, so it appears to be left out except for the reference command as you pointed out.  It sure seems like they need some high-level general discussion on the overall process, especially since it is a departure from install-plugin.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

BUT, here's the first reference to install-plugin in the latest [Grails 2.0 documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html):

"Grails supports Rails-style migrations via the Database Migration plugin which can be installed by running

```
  grails install-plugin database-migration
```

IT WOULD APPEAR GRAILS 2.0 NEEDS TO HAVE AN OVERVIEW SECTION IN CHAPTER 3 -- JUST A FEW WORDS --, EXPLAINING THE DEPARTURE FROM USING INSTALL-PLUGIN, vs CREATING CONFUSION, AND NOT EVEN DOCUMENTING refresh-dependences anywhere in the main [Grails 2.0 document](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html) if one searches for the term.

Otherwise I think developers like myself spend lots of time doing just the opposite of the main goal of what Grails is, wasting hours configuring things and getting them to run together, realizing the exact opposite of the Grail's goal: "the search is over", easy/fast application development.