# Login loop in Amazon Elastic Load Balancer + Spring

Tags: spring, amazon-ec2, spring-security, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have launched a ELB but not able to login to the application. 
Everytime I try to login to the application i keep stuck in a loop. There's no error message.
Application on both these instances are fine when accessed with IP address/path.

I removed one instance from load balancer and tried. Now application is accessible by using ELB after adding another instance it goes to login page but cannot login.

I saw something similar here: [Login loop with Spring Security requires-channel and Amazon Elastic Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405538/login-loop-with-spring-security-requires-channel-and-amazon-elastic-load-balance)
But I am already using the following settings that were suggested: ELB forward 80->80 and 443->443. Setup tomcat to use 80 and 443. 
Setup port mappings to use 80 and 443 on Spring Security

Is there anything am i missing here?

Comment: Do you have stickiness turned on on the load balancer?

Comment: No, stickiness is turned off on the load balancer

Comment: You need to have stickiness turned on for this to work.  Think about the process, you log into instance-a but the next session (next page you go to) might run on instance-b who has no idea who you are because you have no spring mvc security credentials.  I am having similar problems.  I have sticky sessions turned on but cannot find the login page during the login process.  Did you ever get this to work and if so what was the fix?